# Why move constructor does not called without std::move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I've got this code:

```
SomeType::SomeType(std::vector<Item>&& container, const float someOtherPArameter)
    : internal_container(std::move(container))
{
    // some code here
}
```

Can somebody explain to me why a move constructor does not call for the 'internal_container' without 'std::move'?

Comment: Things with names are lvalues (even if they were declared as rvalue reference). Don't ask me why

Comment: @Matt McNabb Because the program may still refer to them. The philosophy is, it's only OK to steal the guts of an object if the program can't look at it anymore anyway (except perhaps in its destructor). Only unnamed temporaries qualify. `std::move` is a way for the program to override that, to give explicit permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move constructor is called whenever an object is initialized from xvalue of the same type. You can create that `xvalue` by calling `std::move(x)`. Declaring a parameter as an rvalue reference will not automatically make it an `xvalue`.

Comment: In your first sentence, `s/xvalue/rvalue/`.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
SomeType::SomeType(std::vector<Item>&& container, const float someOtherPArameter)
    : internal_container(container)
{
    // the parameter container is in scope here
}
```

It would be pretty surprising if, inside the constructor body, accesses to the parameter `container` found a moved-from object.  (It would also break code that was perfectly valid in C++03)

That's why you have to explicitly enable move.